# Null pointers and application crashing

Tags: c++, pointers

This is more of a theoretical question. Why do c++ applications crash when following null pointers?

Is the crashing mechanic there on purpose to protect the system the app is running on or an unavoided fact the comes from the very core of the language? If it is the latter, is automatic handling of null pointers something that could be expected in the future?

Comment: It's undefined behavior.  Some operating systems crash the process when dereferencing a null pointer.  Other operating systems let's the program blissfully continue, unaware they are running with a broken axle.

Comment: Bit of both. A program is liable to crash when writing outside valid memory and NULL was a great place to put a block of memory that was guaranteed to be invalid to make for easy testing and crashing.

Comment: Dereferencing a null pointer leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). What happens then is unpredictable. It might *seem* to work, or you could have a crash.

Comment: I'm curious to know what you think "automatic handling" should do.

Comment: @Beta The same thing as the telepathic compiler does. What I want the program to do regardless of what I told it. I can't wait for mandatory telepathy in C++988

Comment: @user4581301 they have to make it optional in C++955 first, right after they finally get concepts and modules to the language. But I am afraid they will manage to get them after telepathy.

Comment: You aren't afraid that you might be optimized away by the Compiler (blessed be its name)?

Comment: You need not worry, citizen. Trust the compiler. The compiler is your friend.

Comment: In Compiler we trust - that will be imprinted on physical Bitcoin bill.

Comment: Where would you expect a `nullptr` to point to? What would *you* expect sensible behaviour to be when following such a pointer? To me, "take down the application since this is clearly wrong" seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: I never said it was wrong or anything. I simply didn't understand the reason behind it and wanted to know about it. If you think this is a good enough reason to make fun of me and my question then I don't know what to say.

Comment: To be honest, Balgy, it's not that bad a question. Might be a duplicate or two out there, but that's it. What we're giggling over is the concept of Automatic handling. In order to make that work, the compiler would have to know what you wanted it to do, and that kind of ruins the whole Automatic angle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ applications *can* crash when following null pointers. Nothing in the C++ standard says they will. The attempt to dereference a null pointer invokes what is called "undefined behavior", meaning the standard refuses to say what can happen.

As for why most cases result in a crash, most compilers cheat and make a null pointer point at byte 0, and many OSes make address 0 unwritable (and sometimes unreadable as well) so attempts to access the address trigger a processor fault.

As for automatically handling the problem, that's exactly the point of triggering a fault. (The alternative would be to let the program run amok.) There's no further automation that can be done past that point -- the program has gone off the rails and can't be trusted, and the OS has no way to know what you were trying to point at.

Answer (score 5):

> Why do c++ applications crash when following null pointers?
>
> ...
>
> or an unavoided fact the comes from the very core of the language?

The standard does not dictate how a platform should/must deal with accessing a null pointer. It's simply undefined behavior. A platform is free to choose whatever action makes sense for them when you follow/dereference a null pointer.

Answer (score 4):

The crash from dereferencing a null pointer is because the OS maps an invalid page to addresses near 0, so programs running under the OS will crash upon dereferencing a null pointer instead of corrupting their data. There is nothing that says the OS does this, and if your code is running without an OS (embedded or bare metal), then there likely exists memory at address 0 that can be corrupted by writing to a null pointer.

Comment: BTW, not all OS have page swapping or map pages.  Many simple embedded OS don't support virtual memory or paging.

Answer (score 2):

> If it is the latter, is automatic handling of null pointers something that could be expected in the future?

Not unless C++ as a language would go completely different direction. Currently C++ Standard says what you can expect from a valid program, it does not specify what to expect or not to expect when your program misbehaves, so I would not expect any standard additional handling for this or other situations that lead to UB. Some platforms though may or may not do some automatic actions, but I doubt it will become standard way in this language.